# using unity webPlayer in a PyQt MainWindow in maya : the application don't quit

Tags: background, unity-game-engine, maya

I'm using unity webPlayer for create a tool witch interacts with maya (using TcpClient sockets). I'm loading the webPlayer in a PyQT MainWindow in maya (I'm loading the html file with QWebView.load( my url ) int this window which is parented to maya) .

My problem is that when I close the window with Mywindow.close(), it seems that unity is still running in background somewhere and so I just can't quit maya correctly (the maya process is still running after I click on close) ...

Do somebody have any idea of where the problem could be ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using QApplication instance with maya by default, so you need to kill that instance before exiting maya. Here is a small tip and thanks to justin :)

```
app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    __running = False
    for obj in app.topLevelWidgets():
        if obj.objectName()=="your_we_playter_name" and obj.isVisible():
            obj.deleteLater()
```

Comment: I just tried deleteLater(), the QWidget is deleted but maya still don't close :( ... It seems that it's the fact to load the unity3D content who causes the trouble ... (All works well when I delete the lines which load it). I do call an html page which fill the QWidget with javascript.

Comment: I think you need to delete the qapp instance itself.

Comment: thanks for answering again =). I can't delete the qapp because the qapp is maya. I've parent the Qwindow with maya.when I declare a Qapp in the script, the window open and close directly.

Comment: Yeah thats the issue, maya is using qapp instance so you can re implement close event something like this `def closeEvent(self,event):
        del self
        event.accept()`
hope this will help :)

Comment: After an other day to try to debug my script, I've conclude that the problem is linked with the fact to load the unity plugin in maya and not especially with Pyqt. I suppose that it opens something which is running in background and prevent maya from closing (even if I can't see it in my task manager)...

Comment: I just don't see a solution for this specific problem ... the solution would be to run my unity app in an external browser but my boss won't like it =/